# Pass ImageSource Binding from Camera to another Page?

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.forms, media-player

how  to pass  an Image stored in another page(page 1 ) into  a  "OnPhoto1_Clicked"(page 2)

page 2 navigate to page 1 to take a picture from camera or album , page 1 render the image itself.

page 2 :

```
async void OnPhoto1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            await App.Navigator.PushAsync(new TakePic());

        }
```

page 1 :

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    file.Dispose();
                    return stream;
                });
            };
```

Any help very much appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Your question reminded me of a great post: http://blog.adamkemp.com/2015/03/decoupling-views-advanced-ux-flows.html

Comment: In some way, the pages should share a reference to something which a) owns the photo, and b) raises an event when the photo is updated. You don't want to "pass a binding" from page 1 to page 2; you want them both to bind to the same thing.